# How do you talk about a word or phrase itself?

Tags: grammar, usage, english-to-japanese

Basically, I want to know how to talk about the meta properties of a word or phrase while mentioning said word or phrase in the same sentence.

Maybe って is somehow involved, but I don't know even know how to search for the question I'm asking.

---

For example, maybe I want to say something like:

> I don't like the word '料理' (because it is hard to pronounce).
>
> 発音が難しいから「料理」が好きじゃない。

or with a phrase

> 'まーしょうがない' is a useful phrase.
>
> 「まーしょうがない」は便利だ。

In spoken form this makes less sense, as I don't know how to specify "the word/phrase". Do I add anything on to the word or phrase to accomplish this? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: So you know how to say the rest of the sentences?

Comment: @EddieKal I think the original title made more sense than the current one.

Comment: @A.Ellett Either one makes sense to me just fine. By the way I didn't edit the title, if that's what you mean. OP made the title longer in an edit.

Comment: @EddieKal My bad.  I thought that was your edit.

Comment: Yeah, I started writing them out in JP too but then thought there wouldn't be much use to including them in the question. 


Edit: Should I change it back? I thought the original title was a little vague, but I can see how this one is more confusing.

Comment: @A.Ellett Ok I decided to change it back. Now that I'm reading it again now it's really confusing.

Comment: @EvanS. If you include in your question your own effort to construct those sentences, I think it will help potential answerers understand what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Personally, I would have gone with something like 料理ということばは言いにくいから。。。

Comment: Yeah that flows better. ということば was what I was looking for. I found the answer and was typing it up before I could see this. Hopefully it was appropriate to answer my own question.

 It's my first time posting here so thanks to @EddieKal and you for the feedback.

Comment: @EvanS. Yes, it's great that you did some research and wrote an answer to your own question! And welcome to Japanese SE! Hope you stay in the community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use って, but here って is a contraction of と言う; it can also appear as って言う. Here are some options you can choose from:

> 発音が難しいから「料理」って言う言葉が好きじゃない。

> 「料理」と言う言葉が好きじゃない。発音が難しいし。

> 「料理」って言葉が気に入らない。発音が難しいし。

The same goes for the other one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure I found the answer. I had the idea to search 英語で役立つ言葉, and just look at those articles for examples.

The phrase I was looking for was 「という言葉」.

To answer the first example with this:

> 「料理」という言葉が好きじゃない。

Some confirmation would still be nice, but I am quite confident this is it.